# C# .net Core call Oracle function error not a valid month

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core

In Oracle I have a function in package:

```
function get_trans (
  in_idcard in number,
  in_datefrom in date,
  in_dateto in date
)
return trans_rec_list parallel_enable pipelined;
```

If I call func via SQL Developer like this:

```
select field1, field12 from table(API.get_trans(1,TO_DATE('01/06/2018 00:00:00'), TO_DATE('21/06/2018 00:00:00')));
```

Everything works correctly, but when I call function from C# .net Core like this:

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("MyConnectionString")) {
  connection.Open();

  using (OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("select field1, field12 from table(API.get_trans({0}, TO_DATE('{2}'), TO_DATE('{3}')))", 1, dates.Date_From.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), dates.Date_To.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

    OracleDataReader er = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I've got error `ORA-01843: not a valid month`

Finally if I just copy text from `cmd.CommandText` and run in SQL Developer - everything work well

Also another similar functions without work with type `date` parameters work well

where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the date format to be independent from NLS settings of environment.
So instead of `TO_DATE('01/06/2018 00:00:00')` you should use `TO_DATE('01/06/2018 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`